# writing JSON Data format to database in JAVA

Tags: java, jquery, json

I am trying to write JSON data to database. How to send each column to corresponding column in database. I tried to putting the data in

```
var data = JSON.parse(data)
```

and that didn't work. Variable data only showed info in below format:

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

My actual data in in below format. I get the below data after writing below code. How to save this data in Database?

// Code to generate below output.

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
 $("#check").click(function(){

 var rows = $('#jqxgrid').jqxGrid('getrows');

 var rowData = JSON.stringify(rows);

$.post("GridValues.jsp", {"rowValues": rowData });

 });
    });
```

//Output if you print rowData is below

```
[{"empId":"1","fname":"Henry","lname":"Rey","empcat":"Staff","dept":"IT","jTitle":"Software Engg","rAccess":"New Hire","lManager":"Admin","sDate":"2012-10-11","eDate":"2012-10-11","uid":0},{"empId":"2","fname":"Nick","lname":"Murry","empcat":"Staff","dept":"IT","jTitle":"Administrator","rAccess":"New Hire","lManager":"Admin","sDate":"2012-10-11","eDate":"2012-10-11","uid":1},{"empId":"3","fname":"John","lname":"Danilo","empcat":"Staff","dept":"IT","jTitle":"Administrator","rAccess":"New Hire","lManager":"Admin","sDate":"2012-10-11","eDate":"2012-10-11","uid":2},{"empId":"4","fname":"Joene","lname":"Anson","empcat":"Staff","dept":"IT","jTitle":"Software Engg","rAccess":"New Hire","lManager":"Admin","sDate":"2012-10-11","eDate":"2012-10-11","uid":3}]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "JAVA Variable"? How does the JSP and the Javascript communicate?

Comment: I  used $.post("filename", {"rowValues": rowData });  to send data from Jquery output to JAVA

Comment: @ downvoter, may I know the reason for downvoting?

Answer (score 0):

I can't say i fully understand your question, here is a useful SO answer that may help you. You might also want to look at the [Jackson JSON](http://jackson.codehaus.org/)

Comment: My question is simple. How to save JSON format data to Database in JAVA. I provided the data JSON format in my question.

Comment: is the database relational? or document based? json is a string and you can simply save it in a column of datatype `varchar` or `nvarchar`

Comment: Database is relational and all columns are nvarchar except empId (INT), sDate and edate are Date format.

Comment: you should clarify this in your question that you want to deserialize the json and then save it in the database the SO answer's link i have provided and the json processor link (Jackson JSON) does the same thing that you are trying to do, first deserialize the json you have got and afterwards save it in the database